# simple-peer webrtc error when trying to share screen

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I am building a video chat application using simple-peer where users can also share the screen. The flow of the app is such that when user A creates a room, he can grab the page url and share with user B. When user B joins, an initiator peer is created for him as seen here.

```
function createPeer(partnerID, callerID, stream) {
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: true,
            trickle: false,
            stream,
        });

        peer.on("signal", signal => {
            const payload = {
                partnerID,
                callerID,
                signal
            }
            socketRef.current.emit("call partner", payload);
        });

        peer.on("stream", handleStream);

        return peer;
    }
```

When user A gets the offer from user B, a non initiator peer is created for him as seen here.

```
function addPeer(incomingSignal, callerID, stream) {
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: false,
            trickle: false,
            stream,
        });

        peer.on("signal", signal => {
            const payload = {
                callerID,
                signal
            }
            socketRef.current.emit("accept call", payload);
        });

        peer.on("stream", handleStream);

        peer.signal(incomingSignal);
        return peer;
    }
```

Now when any user decides to share their screen, this function gets called.

```
 function shareScreen() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then(stream => {
            const track = stream.getTracks()[0];
            peerRef.current.removeStream(videoStream.current);
            peerRef.current.addStream(stream);
            userVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
            track.onended = function () {
               userVideoRef.current.srcObject = videoStream.current;
               peerRef.current.removeTrack(track, stream);
            };
        });
    }
```

What's really strange about the behavior that I am getting, is that when user B, in other words the calling peer, wants to share his screen, all works well, but when user A, the callee peer, wants to share his screen, I get the following error.

> index.js:17 Uncaught Error: [object RTCErrorEvent]
>       at makeError (index.js:17)
>       at RTCDataChannel._channel.onerror (index.js:490)

I am not really sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I discovered where the error is coming from.

What you need to do is to call the function `peer.signal(incomingSignal)` after calling the function `addPeer()`, along with the `peer` variable returned from the `addPeer()` function.

Here's an example:

```
function addPeer(incomingSignal, callerID, stream) {
    const peer = new Peer({
        initiator: false,
        trickle: false,
        stream,
    });

    peer.on("signal", signal => {
        const payload = {
            callerID,
            signal
        }
        socketRef.current.emit("accept call", payload);
    });

    peer.on("stream", handleStream);

    // peer.signal(incomingSignal);
    return peer;
}
let peer = addPeer(incomingSignal, callerId, stream);
peer.signal(incomingSignal);
```

and it will work fine